# Centos internet not working

Tags: centos, static-ip

We have our test server configured with a CentOS installation. However, when we put the machine on Dynamic IP then the internet works fine.

But we need static IP to configure it with the internet (ironically) and make the machine accessible. However, on Static IP internet does not work.

What could be the problem?

P.S: on Static IP, machine is accessible from internet (incoming traffic is working fine).

Edit: here is the information for all. http://paste2.org/p/1741156

Comment: `sudo /sbin/ifconfig`? `sudo /sbin/route -n`? `ping -c 4 8.8.8.8`? `nslookup google.com`?

Comment: @quanta I have the answers in a big text file, where do I attach that?

Comment: Paste to the pastebin.com and insert link here.

Comment: @quanta pasted above

Comment: What make you think the default gateway is your problem when you can ping 8.8.8.8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check the default gateway

```
#route 

Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.61.0    *               255.255.255.192 U     1      0        0 eth0
192.168.122.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
#check the following line
default         192.168.61.62   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

if not you need to set default gateway

```
route add default gw 10.0.0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[root@192 ~]# nslookup google.com
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

You didn't setup the DNS. Run the following commands:

```
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" > /etc/resolv.conf
echo "nameserver 8.8.4.4" >> /etc/resolv.conf
```

and try again.